# information is returned vs are returned

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which of the following sentences are grammatical?

> The place,  weather and rescue team information is returned to the
>   user.
>
> The place,  weather and rescue team information are returned to the
>   user.

Comment: They're both grammatical. The second is correct because it is an ellipsis for *"the place information, weather information, and rescue team information are returned to the user."*

Comment: Just wondering if my answer answered your question to your satisfaction? If so, perhaps you could mark it as accepted by selecting the green tick next to my answer. If not, do let me know what you still need help with and I'll be happy to edit!

Answer (score 2):

The correctness depends on your meaning.

> The place, weather and rescue team information is returned to the user.

This means that you are refurning the following to the user:

- information about the place, weather and rescue team.

> The place, weather and rescue team information are returned to the user.

This means that you are refurning the following to the user:

- the place
- the weather
- information about the rescue team

I think that the meaning you probably want is the first one. However, that sentence is a bit clumsy; I would recommend rephrasing to:

> The information about the place, weather and rescue team is returned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, but the second one is not. Information is an uncountable noun; the sentence, in other words, means that the information on the place, weather and rescue team is returned to the user.